# Neo4j 3.0.3 HA cluster doesnot start

Tags: neo4j

Neo4j 3.0.3 HA cluster fails to start with the following error message from the log:

> ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1b38563a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception. Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1b38563a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>       org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1b38563a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>       at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
>   at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:217)
>   at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:87)
>   at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:66)
>   at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:32)
>   Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@1b38563a' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>   at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:189)
>   ... 3 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.ha.factory.HighlyAvailableFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:144)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.factory.HighlyAvailableFacadeFactory.newFacade(HighlyAvailableFacadeFactory.java:42)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:41)
>   at org.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseNeoServer.lambda$static$0(EnterpriseNeoServer.java:80)
>   at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:89)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
>   ... 5 more
>   Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin@27564996' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:140)
>   ... 10 more
>   Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
>   at org.neo4j.cluster.statemachine.StateMachineProxyFactory$ResponseFuture.get(StateMachineProxyFactory.java:300)
>   at org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin.joinByConfig(ClusterJoin.java:143)
>   at org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin.start(ClusterJoin.java:82)
>   at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
>   ... 14 more

Answer (score 1):

Since there's a timeout, it's probably an error in the network configuration of the cluster: wrong IP addresses, TCP port filtered by a firewall, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on 3.0.1 in an 2 node ha cluster with an arbiter. However, my arbiter fails first, and if I restart it two more times while the nodes are still trying to start, I'm able to start entire cluster.  This is a ridiculous procedure, but this is the only on I've found so far to start the cluster. And not, it is not a networking issue, because after that elaborate restart, everything is working.